# How can I repeat animation (using UIViewPropertyAnimator) certain number of times?

Tags: swift, animation, ios10

I want to achieve pulsation effect for the button, and hence need to repeat the spring effect several number of times, the issue is that I can't find any information about what parameters to provide and how to do it

```
let btnView = sayWordBtn.viewWithTag(0)
    btnView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
    let mass: CGFloat = 2.0 // weight of the object
        let stiffness: CGFloat = 25.0 //elasticity
        let damping: CGFloat = 2*sqrt(mass*stiffness) // point where the system comes to rest in the shortest period of time
        let underDamping: CGFloat = damping * 0.5
        let initialVelocity: CGVector = CGVector.zero
        let springParameters: UISpringTimingParameters = UISpringTimingParameters(mass: mass, stiffness: stiffness, damping: underDamping, initialVelocity: initialVelocity)
        let animationDelay = 3

        let pulseEffect = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5, timingParameters: springParameters)
        pulseEffect.addAnimations( {[weak self] in
          btnView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
          })
        pulseEffect.isReversed = true
        pulseEffect.startAnimation(afterDelay: TimeInterval(animationDelay))
```

Answer (score 13):

**iOS 10** introduces a new object called [`UIViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator).
You can do the same things you did with `UIView.animation` but for achieving more complex animations, apple provides us `CoreAnimation` framework.

### Why we should use it?

Because `UIViewPropertyAnimator` is a well-written and highly-extensible API. It covers a lot of the same functionality as the ‘old-style’ `UIView` animations, but gives you fine-grained programmatic control over the animation. This means you can pause an in-progress animation, restart it at a later date if you wish and even dynamically modify the animatable properties (such as changing the animation’s end point to the top-right of the screen when it was previously the bottom-left).
We create an instance of it and create an animation as follows:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
view.alpha = 0.35 
view.backgroundColor = .red
self.view.addSubview(view)
let newFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
let viewFrameAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1.0, 
                                                  curve: .linear, 
                                             animations: { view.frame = newFrame })
```

Now we can interacting with the animations using:

```
viewFrameAnimator.startAnimation..
viewFrameAnimator.stopAnimation..
viewFrameAnimator.finishAnimation(at:..
```

to continue the example above:

```
viewFrameAnimator.startAnimation()
```

Then, to return to `alpha` equal to **1**, if we need more animations options, we can also launch [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator/1648367-runningpropertyanimator) `UIViewPropertyAnimator` open class:

```
let viewAlphaAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1.0, 
                                                       delay: 0.0,
                                                     options: [.curveLinear],
                                                  animations: { view.alpha = 1.0 })
```

let give us to add more animation options. Now you know more than this new object.

### How to repeat it?

So let's start to explain how to repeat the animation, for example if we want to repeat the `view.alpha = 1.0` for **3** times (you can see the little flash light for each repeation to output..) you should follow:

```
let viewAlphaAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1.0,
                                                delay: 0.0,
                                                options: [.curveLinear,.repeat],
                                                animations: { UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(3);view.alpha = 1.0 })
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that you had to send `UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount()`, basically a class side global setting from the old API, kind of indicate that this new framework is not actually much better or more powerful than the old one? Perhaps more succinct for simple cases, but that doesn't strike me as elegant or powerful. If UIViewPropertyAnimator had a repeatCount like other animation objects, that would be the "more correct" thing, IMO.

Comment: setAnimationRepeatCount is deprecated. Now how do we repeat it?

Comment: Apple starts to put these options in blocks, try to looking for `options: [.autoreverse, .curveEaseIn, .repeat]`...

Answer (score 5):

'setAnimationRepeatCount' was deprecated in iOS 13.0. Options: [.autoreverse, .repeat] is not working too.

```
var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator!

func start(_ reversed: Bool = false) {
    animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator()
    animator.addAnimations {
        //
    }
    animator.addCompletion { _ in
        start(!reversed)
    }
    animator.startAnimation()
}

func stop() {
    animator.stopAnimation(true)
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Helped me stop an animation far quicker. The old way of animating actually delayed my UI refresh by 3 full seconds (lots of short animations ~0.05s each chained together for a back&forth-effect)! This one is instant :)

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason they left out the ability to specify a repeat count with UIPropertyAnimator.  You are left with he following options:

1. Keep a counter and repeat the animation in the completion handler
   and decrement the counter until the counter reaches 0
2. Animate with an indefinite repeat but schedule a timer and halt the
   animation (optionally add an animation to move to the final
   position)
3. Adjust your spring parameters so that there is less dampening and
   more elasticity and you will get more oscillations.
4. Use the old UIView.animate methods along with the old
   [UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622419-setanimationrepeatcount)
5. Use CASpringAnimation since thats what the Property animator is wrapping anyways, and it does have a repeat count.

Answer (score 2):

Please use

```
    pulseEffect.addCompletion({_ in
            // Repeat the logic here
    })
```

You can repeat the animation logic inside the addCompletion block

```
func animateView() {
    btnView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
    let mass: CGFloat = 2.0 // weight of the object
    let stiffness: CGFloat = 25.0 // elasticity
    let damping: CGFloat = 2*sqrt(mass*stiffness) // point where the system comes to rest in the shortest period of time
    let underDamping: CGFloat = damping * 0.5
    let initialVelocity: CGVector = CGVector.zero
    let springParameters: UISpringTimingParameters = UISpringTimingParameters(mass: mass, stiffness: stiffness, damping: underDamping, initialVelocity: initialVelocity)
    let animationDelay = 3

    let pulseEffect = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5, timingParameters: springParameters)
    pulseEffect.addAnimations( {[weak self] in
        self?.btnView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        })
    pulseEffect.addCompletion({_ in
        self.animateView()
    })
    pulseEffect.isReversed = true
    pulseEffect.startAnimation(afterDelay: TimeInterval(animationDelay))
}
```

You can also add the logic to restrict the animation to specific number in the addCompletion block

Comment: Won't this eventually cause an, ahem, "Stack Overflow"?

Comment: @gmw, there is no stack overflow because this is not recursive. The completion block is not run at the end of this function, it is queued and/or called after this function returns (and releases its stack space).

Comment: This code repeats the animation indefinitely but it also makes any calls to `UIViewPropertyAnimator.stopAnimation(true)` meaningless, no? So the animation cannot be stopped... At least this is the problem I'm now encountering

Answer (score 0):

Please use this modified code

```
let btnView = sayWordBtn.viewWithTag(0)
btnView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
let mass: CGFloat = 2.0 // weight of the object
let stiffness: CGFloat = 25.0 //elasticity
let damping: CGFloat = 2*sqrt(mass*stiffness) // point where the system comes to rest in the shortest period of time
let underDamping: CGFloat = damping * 0.5
let initialVelocity: CGVector = CGVector.zero
let springParameters: UISpringTimingParameters = UISpringTimingParameters(mass: mass, stiffness: stiffness, damping: underDamping, initialVelocity: initialVelocity)
let animationDelay = 3

let pulseEffect = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5, timingParameters: springParameters)
pulseEffect.addAnimations( {[weak self] in
    UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(3)
    UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)
    btnView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
})
pulseEffect.isReversed = true
pulseEffect.startAnimation(afterDelay: TimeInterval(animationDelay))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
func usePropertyAnimator(_ reversed: Bool = false) {

    let circleAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(
        duration: 2, timingParameters: UICubicTimingParameters())

    circleAnimator.addAnimations {
        circle.center.y += (reversed ? -1 : 1) * 330
    }

    circleAnimator.addCompletion { _ in
        usePropertyAnimator(!reversed)
    }

    circleAnimator.startAnimation()

}

usePropertyAnimator()
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to add an animation to an animator <UIViewPropertyAnimator(0x6000001f4000) [unknown] running interruptible> as it is completing'