# UIViewPropertyAnimator repeat

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I've taken a look at the answers in the following StackOverflow question but none seem to work for me: on the execution of the completion block, instead of performing the animation again, the program spews out "complete" ad infinitum without animating the view at all.

[How can I repeat animation (using UIViewPropertyAnimator) certain number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438008/how-can-i-repeat-animation-using-uiviewpropertyanimator-certain-number-of-time)

This is my `AnimatorFactory` class:

```
class AnimatorFactory {

    @discardableResult
    static func rotateRepeat(view: UIView) -> UIViewPropertyAnimator {
        let rotate = UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
        }, completion: { _ in
            print("complete")
            self.rotateRepeat(view: view)
        })

        return rotate
    }

}
```

It is called as you'd expect with `AnimatorFactory.rotateRepeat(view: <someView>)`

However, the problem as mentioned above occurs. What I'd expect is that the view would rotate repeatedly until some time that I decide to change or stop it; this is exactly the reason that I have chosen to use `UIViewPropertyAnimator` instead of `UIView.animate(withDuration:animations)`.

What's the best way then to create interactive, repeatable UIView animations? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine. The trouble is that your animation does nothing after the first time. You say:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
```

The first time, we change the rotation from 0 to pi. That is a change, so there is animation. But after that we just keep saying “stay at pi” over and over. We are at pi and you say to stay there, so there is no change to animate.

What you want each animation to do is *add* pi, not *be* pi.

Comment: Also it is silly to call `runningPropertyAnimator`. If you do that, you don’t need a view property animator.

Comment: a `runningPropertyAnimator` still returns an animator instance... So it's a lot easier to interact with over the UIView.animate() method

Comment: No my point is the opposite. Use the view property animator. But code the view property animator correctly, don’t be lazy.

Answer (score 2):

As @matt suggested, I was merely setting the rotation of the view to .pi over and over. So in the completion block I have now set the transform to .identity before kicking the animation off again.

```
class AnimatorFactory {

    @discardableResult
    static func rotateRepeat(view: UIView) -> UIViewPropertyAnimator {
        let rotate = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1.0, curve: .linear)
        rotate.addAnimations {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
        }
        rotate.addCompletion{ _ in
            view.transform = .identity
            self.rotateRepeat(view: view)
        }
        rotate.startAnimation()

        return rotate
    }

}
```